# Sencha touch 2 and blackberry

Tags: cordova, blackberry, sencha-touch

Since I don't know if my newly edited, 1 month-old unanswered question will be in the first pages or not, I'm posting another question for this painful subject.

As stated in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12384017/692507) question,  I tried to add a specific viewport for blackberry. And now I am testing the app on a BB 7 simulator and **BB 6 TORCH** (TOUCH YEAH).

This time, however, I'm stuck at splash screen. Even though I can see the splash at full size, neither the Browser of the device/simulator nor the app itself get past the splash screen.

What might be the problem now? The reason I'm stuck is that I can't seem to **debug** in any way. At least any ways of doing that is a start, big one at that.

Help is vastly appreciated.

**EDIT**

Thanks to @Anzor for the debugging answer. As of now, here is the issue:
I found out that the app will crash if it is too heavy for BB. Meaning, Chrome and Safari won't tell you if it's gonna work well on BB.

I minimized my app for that purpose, but it still crashes. So again, I cannot debug. I'm starting to lose hope, but yeah, you never know.

Answer (score 1):

RIM has introduced a great debugger for WebWorks Applications in OS version 7.0+. You have a number of options.

1. You can use a 7.x+ device OR simulator and connect to it using Web Inspector.
2. Use Ripple simulator which has support for Apache PhoneGap 2.0. You can see the errors in red within the Chrome Development Console as you run the application.

For more information on Web Inspector, go here https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/getting_started_webinsp_microsite_1987477_11.html

Tip: CTRL+R in the Web Inspector within the Console tab will refresh the application on the device it is connected to. I use this to debug initialization issues as it's often impossible to time it manually to begin capture on app init.

Edit: This is considering you are using WebWorks to package the application.

Comment: I recently found out about this, but it doesn't help with my current issue. Big thanks anyway!